# C# RestSharp - Deserialize non standard JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to use RestSharp to Deserialize a JSON string. However I am getting caught on the slightly non standard structure around the "555111222" part.

The number 555111222 is a device serial number so it can change or there can be multiple serial numbers in the JSON response.

```
{
"requestid": "42",
"data": {
    "555111222": {
        "gps_data": [
            {
                "longitude": -73.952284,
                "latitude": 40.755988,
                "time": "2016-06-30 09:41:21"
            },
            {
                "longitude": -73.952284,
                "latitude": 40.755988,
                "time": "2016-06-30 09:41:22"
            },
            {
                "longitude": -73.952284,
                "latitude": 40.755988,
                "time": "2016-06-30 09:41:23"
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Json2csharp.com gives me the following

```
public class GpsData
{
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__555111222
{
    public List<GpsData> gps_data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public __invalid_type__555111222 __invalid_name__555111222 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string requestid { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Im not sure how to handle the **invalid_type** errors in my class.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to access the different serial numbers in the JSON response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like your `Data` property should be `Dictionary<string, GpsDataWrapper>` where `GpsDataWrapper` is just a class with a `GpsData` property:

```
public class GpsData
{
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class GpsDataWrapper
{
    public List<GpsData> gps_data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string requestid { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, GpsDataWrapper> data { get; set; }
}
```

I'd personally then convert all of these to use .NET naming conventions and apply attributes to specify the names used in JSON.